# ffmpeg -filter_complex "pad,overlay" makes file with 2 video

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

i try to make video with watermark.

"H:\ffmpeg.exe" -i video.mov -i watermark.png -map 0:0 -c:v libx264 -vsync 0 -vb 3M -filter_complex "pad=2048:1152:0:147:black,overlay" -map 0:1 -c:a aac -ac 2 -ab 448k video_watermark.mp4 -report

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2023-03-23T20:09:02.000000Z
  Duration: 01:34:56.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 27054 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng), 1, 1/24: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 2048x858, 20136 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-23T20:09:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Обработчик видео Apple
      vendor_id       : appl
      encoder         : H.264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng), 47, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32 (24 bit), 6912 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-23T20:09:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Обработчик звука Apple
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Successfully opened the file.
```

ffmpeg makes file with 2 video. Why?

```
Output #0, mp4, to 'video_watermark.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf60.4.100
  Stream #0:0, 0, 1/12288: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 2048x1152, q=2-31, 3000 kb/s, 24 fps, 12288 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.6.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/3000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng), 0, 1/12288: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 2048x858, q=2-31, 3000 kb/s, 24 fps, 12288 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-23T20:09:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Обработчик видео Apple
      vendor_id       : appl
      encoder         : Lavc60.6.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/3000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:2(eng), 0, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-23T20:09:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Обработчик звука Apple
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.6.101 aac
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.45 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=1.88x    


ffmpeg version N-110065-g30cea1d39b-20230323 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.152_89671bf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two maps in your command, and the first map maps the original video stream. The output from the filter complex is the 2nd video stream in the output.

You should label all pads in the filter complex and map the output.

`ffmpeg.exe -i video.mov -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]pad=2048:1152:0:147:black[v];[v][1]overlay[v]" -map [v] -map 0:1 -c:v libx264 -vsync 0 -b:v 3M -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 448k video_watermark.mp4`